# Relative links don't resolve as expected when doing Visual Studio 2013 debugging

Tags: asp.net, directory, visual-studio-2013, vs-web-site-project

I have an ASP.Net website that I'd like to attempt to debug using the built-in run/debug option.

My asp.net pages reside in a directory:

C:\MyWebSite\dev\

The "MyWebSite" directory is the desired main directory of my site, and contains various subfolders for images, etc. which I do not wish to have as part of the ASP.NET project itself, but still be referenceable from the asp.net web pages.

The source for the home page is:

C:\MyWebSite\dev\home.aspx

which runs as:

localhost:58153/home.aspx

However, relative links called from that page (e.g. "/images/myImage.png") aren't resolving as expected: I'd expect them to resolve to C:\MyWebsite\images\myImage.png") -- apparently, they're resolving relative to the dev directory which houses the asp.net code--i.e., C:\MyWebSite\dev\images\myimage.png

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio 2013 to use the "MyWebsite" directory as the base for the website? It seems the older options present in VS2012 to set the working directory are no longer part of standard website builds in VS 2013.

Comment: Can you post the links markup?

Comment: Really just <img src="/images/myimage.png" alt="something" /> . the "/" would ideally resolve to the C:\MyWebSite directory--instead, it resolves to "C:\MyWebsite\dev" (presumably since that's where the asp.net pages lie. What I'd really like is a way of setting the base directory for the site in IIS Express.